# Using heapq.nlargest with a Percentage - Python

Tags: python, percentage

Does anyone know how to use heapq.nlargest with a percentage rather than a number? At the moment I have

```
heapq.nlargest(187030, y)
```

But this gets me the top 187030 numbers. I need it to get me the top 10% of numbers for each array because not all arrays have 1.8 million.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Behind the curtains a heap is actually a list with certain properties (it uses what is called an [*implicit data structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_data_structure)).

So we can first take `len(y)` to obtain the number of elements. By dividing by `10`, we get the 10% *number* of elements. So we can use:

```
heapq.nlargest(len(y)//10, y)
```

Or in case you want to use a percentage as parameter:

```
p = 17  # top 17 procent

heapq.nlargest(len(y)*p//100, y)
```

You can also use a *fraction* (for instance the top `0.14`):

```
from math import round

p = 0.14  # top 14 procent

heapq.nlargest(round(len(y)*p), y)
```

Comment: Hey Willem, I'm using this function to overlay some histograms using a for loop. The code currently looks like this yy = heapq.nlargest(len(df1.iloc[:,i])//10, df1.iloc[:,i]) . This seems to get me only the top 10% of my first array, and not for each individual array. Do you have any further pointers? Thanks

Comment: @Bake.G: can you edit your question, or ask a new one with perhaps some sampel dataframe. Now it is a bit hard to understand what you aim to do exactly.

Comment: Yeah sure, I have to wait another while in order to ask a question (90 minute limits!). So it'll be up in the next few minutes. Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48567497/overlapping-histogram-in-for-loop-with-heapq-nlargest-python